# Trying to call two AI functions in the render method in react but they're called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, render

I'm working on a board game with an AI mode in it. And now I'm trying to call the AI's move but it is called asynchronously. I don't know what I can do. I've tried a lot of stuff; calling setTimeout synchronously, calling it inside the onClick... Do you have any solutions?

Here's the code:

```
render() {
        // datas that will be rendered regularly come here
        const current = this.state.history[this.state.stepNumber]
        const elemsPlayer = this.checkElementsAround(this.checkEmptySpaces())

        if (this.state.ourPlayer !== (this.state.blackIsNext) ? 'black' : 'white') {
            if (this.state.gameMode === "AI-Easy") {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.easyAI()
                }, 1500)
            } else if (this.state.gameMode === "AI-Hard") {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.minimaxAI()
                }, 1500)
            }
        }

        // Return the game scene here
        return (
            <div id="master-container">
                <div id="gameboard-container">
                    <GameBoard squares={current} onClick={(row,col) => {
                        // Where player's move will be called
                    }}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here's the easyAI function (minimax one is empty for now):

```
easyAI(){
        const elemsAI = this.checkElementsAround(this.checkEmptySpaces())
        const validsAI = []
        for (let elAI=0;elAI<elemsAI.length;elAI++) {
            const turningAI = this.checkTurningStones(elemsAI[elAI].directions, this.state.blackIsNext)
            //console.log(turningAI)
            if (turningAI.length !== 0) {
                validsAI.push(elemsAI[elAI])
            }
        }

        // ValidsAI returns an object {emptySquares: coordinates of the empty square, turningStones: coordinates of the stones that will be turned upside down if emptySquares is played}

        //Check if AI has a move to make
        if (validsAI.length !== 0) {
            //Perform the move
            var elementToTurnAI = null
            try{
                elementToTurnAI = validsAI[Math.floor(Math.random()*validsAI.length)]
            } catch {
                console.log(null)
            }
            //console.log(elementToTurnAI)
            const turningAI = this.checkTurningStones(elementToTurnAI.directions, this.state.blackIsNext)
            const selfAI = elementToTurnAI.coordinates
            //console.log(selfAI)
            //console.log(turningAI)
            turningAI.unshift([selfAI[0],selfAI[1]])
            // Turn the stones
            const upcomingAI = this.handleMove(turningAI)
            // Update the state
            this.setState({
                history: upcomingAI,
                stepNumber: upcomingAI.length - 1
            },() => {
                    this.setWinnerAndTurn(this.state.history)
                //console.log(this.state.history)
            })
        }
    }
```

If you have to take a look at something else in order to find a solution, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide your this.easyAI() and this.minimaxAI() functions

Comment: minimaxAI is empty for now, I'll put the other one right now

Comment: Did it right now, you can check the easyAI function

Comment: I see, the function seems very straightforward. But not able to get your main problem. Can you please describe it more.

Comment: The problem is that when the game starts, AI doesn't wait for its turn and plays all by itself

Comment: This is happening because you are calling this function in render. So this function is called as soon as you come to this page. I guess you should call this function when the user1 completes his turn.

Comment: I've tried it. But then, in some exceptional cases the player turn has to be the same. When I come across to such situation, it does not play one more time.